# I/O Capture Time (Interrupt's I/O Changing Time Reaction) of MCU

Tags: microcontroller, interrupts, microchip

I am searching an information from the datahseet about how fast MCU's INTERRUPT can detect the I/0 change on the I/O ports for [PIC12F609](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41302D.pdf) (also it can called as I/0 capture time). I have found a chart in the datasheet's 158 page and there is a parameter as "GPIO interrupt-on-change new input
level time" Do you think that this value is the my parameter? I need this value for [PIC24F16KL402](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/30001037c.pdf) and [ATTINY4-MAHR](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-8127-avr-8-bit-microcontroller-attiny4-attiny5-attiny9-attiny10_datasheet.pdf) MCUs. Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: "How fast" is a vague question. Are you talking about latency (delay for a single event) or sample rate (ability to distinguish multiple events)?

Comment: What i mean with "how fast" is that ability to detect change of I/0 for interrupt.

Comment: OS20 and OS21 give the minimum duration for a detectable change, depending on which kind of interrupt you're using. I wouldn't use the phrase "how fast" to characterize them, however.